# Fraction of $1$s in binary representation of $n!$

Tags: number-theory, limits, factorial, limsup-and-liminf, binary

I plotted a fraction of $1$s in binary representation of $n!$ (i.e. [A079584](https://oeis.org/A079584)/[A072831](https://oeis.org/A072831)) for $n$ from $1$ to $10^4$:
[image]
It appears it might converge to some limit for $n\to\infty$. Can we (dis-)prove that this limit exists, and find its exact value? Or, at least, find the [limit inferior and limit superior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) of the sequence?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it should do anything but converge to one-half. (I can't think of any way to prove this, either.)

Comment: This is related to $$1 \cdot x \cdot (x+1) \cdot x^2 \cdot (x^2+x)\cdot (x^2 + x + 1) \cdot (x^2 + 1) \cdots (x^n + x^{n-1} + \dots + 1) = \sum_{k \geq 0} a_kx^k,$$ where $a_k$ is the number of partitions of $k$ into parts $\leq n$ each occurring with multiplicity $\leq 2^n.$  When $m=2^n + 2^{n-1}+ \dots + 1$, A079584 for $m$ is the number of nonzero $a_k \pmod{2}$.  When $m$ is not of that form, then A079584 for $m$ can still be interpreted in terms of partitions as above, but the conditions on the parts won't be a nice.  Statistics of numbers of parts being well-distributed may be relevant.

Comment: Oops, they are compositions, not partitions.

Comment: If it's not difficult, could you try to pin down the variance as a function of $n$? So for each block of $n$, say $[n-100,n]$, what's the variance of the fraction of 1s, as a function of $n$? Say, something like $C/n$?

Comment: Modelling the number as 1 & [mix] & trailing zeroes, with the mix being 50:50, I get expected values exactly down the trendline of what you see. My expectation is that the contribution of trailing zeroes will become steadily smaller, taking the limit towards $0.5$

Comment: Given that the number of bits is around $\log(n!)/\log(2) \approx n\ln n$, it looks like the number of 1s grows presumably like $(1/2) n\ln(n)/\ln(2)$.

Comment: @Joffan: We get exactly $\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots=1$ trailing zero per factor on average, whereas the number of digits grows as $\sum_k\log_2k\approx n(\log n-1)/\log2$, so we should expect the fraction of digits that are trailing zeros to decay like $\log2/(\log n-1)$.

Comment: Of course, I should have written `Mean[IntegerDigits[n!, 2]]` instead.

Comment: Your plot seems to fit very well with the observation that $n!$ has $\approx n(\ln n-1)/\ln 2$ bits of which we know that the last $\approx n$ bits are $0$  and the rest random